# how to overwrite css that is included in the css

Tags: html, css

I have code in a complex webapp - that is creating code like so

```
<img src="foobar.png" style="width:369px;height:200px;">
```

how can I insert css (via a .css file include) to overwrite width and height ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can override this image style like below method

```css
img[style]{
        height:100px !important;
        width:200px !important;
    }
```

```html
<img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/conquer/assets/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" style="width:369px;height:200px">
```

Answer (score 0):

used to `!important` and define a `class` in your `img` tag as like this

```
.imgClass{
width:400px !important;
height:400px !important
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Force it with CSS using the `!important` method which overrides everything:

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y9rbvLg4/)

```
img {
  width: 500px !important;
  height: 500px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just add the `!important` to your style like so.

```
img {
    height: 200px !important;
    width: 369px !important;
}
```

And then i would allways suggest you not to do inline style.